# UDP sockets - disabling incoming broadcast

Tags: sockets, udp

If I remember correctly, if I disable `SO_BROADCAST` on a UDP socket (whatever programming language), I will not be able to send data to the `255.255.255.255` broadcast address.

Is the following also the case? If I disable `SO_BROADCAST` on a UDP socket, I will not be able to receive data that is sent to `255.255.255.255` when bound to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disable `SO_BROADCAST` (it is already disabled by default), you won't be able to *send* to ANY broadcast IP, not just to `255.255.255.255`.

However, disabling `SO_BROADCAST` has no effect on *receiving* broadcasts.